# json_encode of special chars from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, json, utf-8

I need to encode a result from a MySQL query to JSON format.

My database is in the encoding `utf8_unicode_ci`.

In particular, I have some special chars (for example, €) stored in my database which produce a null value when I apply the PHP function `json_encode`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Related: [How to keep json_encode() from dropping strings with invalid characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663743/how-to-keep-json-encode-from-dropping-strings-with-invalid-characters)

Answer (score 6):

My blind guess is that your MySQL database connection is not set to UTF-8, which leads to ISO-8859-1 characters being returned even if the source database is UTF-8.

[Those characters will break `json_encode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663743/how-to-keep-json-encode-from-dropping-strings-with-invalid-characters) because they are invalid in the UTF-8 character set, which `json_encode()` expects.

You will probably have to set your connection encoding to UTF-8. How to do that depends on the library you are using.

In the `mysql_*` family of functions, one way is

```
mysql_query("SET names utf8;");
```

or in MySQL > 5.0.7, the new

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: thanks. I try to set charset with function "mysql_set_charset" but now he truncate the special chars

Comment: @Dany did you try the first one?

Comment: yes, I try it! I try also to apply the php function iconv but it truncate the special chars