# json_encode php result is NULL?

Tags: php, ajax, null, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [json_encode is returning NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972006/json-encode-is-returning-null)

I'm having a strange problem with `json_encode()` in php. Pretty simple code:

```
$content = json_encode(array('content1' => $arm_length,
                             'content2' => $body_length));
echo $content;
```

`$arm_length` and `$body_length` variables contain the HTML markup for two select dropdown menus. My problem is when it `echo`'s out it show's `NULL` for `content1` and `content2`. If I take the `json_encode()` away and just do `print_r($content)` it shows all the data as it should be.

Does anyone know what's happening here? Is there certain data that can't be parsed into JSON? I've done this a few times now using Ajax/PHP and never had any problems.

Cheers for any help with this.

Comment: All the contained data *must* be valid UTF-8 prior using json_encode().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) has the (undocumented) habit of silently `null`ing properties that contain invalid (= non-UTF-8) characters.

Make sure your input data is UTF-8 encoded, which *is* a documented requirement of that function.

> In the event of a failure to encode, [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/json_last_error) can be used to determine the exact nature of the error. (Available in PHP 5.3 only)

Related:  [How to keep json_encode() from dropping strings with invalid characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663743/how-to-keep-json-encode-from-dropping-strings-with-invalid-characters)

Answer (score 0):

quotes inside your vars " should be escaped like this: \"
you can do that by add_slashes($arm_length)

Also json throws errors on \n (new line) and some other characters, you can find full list here -  http://json.org/