# json_encode encodes strings with Unicode (copyright) character as null?

Tags: php, json, unicode, character-encoding

I am having trouble JSON-encoding special characters.  These characters display normally on my computer, in Notepad, in browsers, and even in my database. However, they do not JSON encode.  An example is as follows:

```
<?
$array['copyright_str'] = "Copyright site.com © 2011-2012";
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

The copyright symbol after site.com is what is making the JSON string echo as `{"copyright_str":null}`.  While this is simple, I have users inputting profile data into a database which can be anything.  When one of these funky characters shows up it breaks things.  What is a good solution to this issue?  The API I coded relies heavily on returning data from the database and printing strings in general as JSON.

My Multibyte settings are as follows:

```
     php -e phpinfo.php  | grep mb
    Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-dbase' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-curlwrappers' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-libexpat-dir=/usr' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mhash=/opt/mhash/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pic' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-sqlite=shared' '--with-ttf' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'
    xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
    mbstring
    Multibyte string engine => libmbfl
    mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.
    mbstring.detect_order => no value => no value
    mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
    mbstring.func_overload => 0 => 0
    mbstring.http_input => pass => pass
    mbstring.http_output => pass => pass
    mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value
    mbstring.language => neutral => neutral
    mbstring.strict_detection => Off => Off
    mbstring.substitute_character => no value => no value
```

I'd like to avoid saving things like `&copy;`.  Some of this data is going to be stored as plain text.

Comment: Is PHP compiled for Unicode/MB? And, furthermore, does `json_encode` work correctly on Unicode/MB?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar There are many Unicode characters that *have no ASCII equivalent*.

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058450/problem-json-encode-utf-8 seems to have a solution, although it doesn't strike me as being the "right" solution. It does seem to *require* UTF-8 or it may *silently result in null* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972006/json-encode-is-returning-null and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938387/json-encode-php-result-is-null (another failed design choice :-/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

encode data in UTF-8 format before passing it to json_encode function

```
<?
    $array['copyright_str'] = utf8_encode("Copyright site.com © 2011-2012");
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: +1 however this does assume that you're storing and handling all your data as ISO-8859-1, which means your app won't support Unicode characters outside of that one encoding. In the long term you are better off completely migrating to UTF-8.

Comment: in that case you can use mb_detect_encoding to check current data is in which format and then convert it to UTF-8 using mb_convert_encoding

Comment: Well... bearing in mind that `mb_detect_encoding` only ever an approximate guess that could easily be wrong, yes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm encoding data with tons of UTF-8 symbols with

```
json_encode($return, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

and it works well. I use it to encode all kinds of languages: Arabic, Chinese, Thai, Lithuanian, German, French, Spanish, etc. All those have different unique symbols. Oh, I haven't tried encoding snowmen ☃ :)

Answer (score -5):

Use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) before `json_encode`

```
<?
$array['copyright_str'] = "Copyright site.com © 2011-2012";
$array['copyright_str'] = urlencode($array['copyright_str']);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: Why? It is not a URL. That would *alter the data* and require the consumer to do the reverse.

Comment: But it will escape the copyright character and convert it to `&copy;`. Reversal is trivial.

Comment: That's not the issue or a solution. Imagine if it's *a different* Unicode character (say a ☃, which is a snowman). How would *that* be handled? If it's a one-off-hacky-edge case, clearly it is *not reliable* (unless there happens to be a *bug* with PHP that *only* affects the Unciode character for the copyright symbol).

Comment: I'de like to avoid storing URLENCODED data in the database as I can't directly edit via phpmyadmin if needbe.

Comment: @xbonez — It won't store it as `&copy;`, that's HTML encoding. The JSON format has its own way of storing the character, there should be no need to nest different data formats.

Comment: only encode data in this format when you want to pass it as url, not for saving it to database