# json_encode character exclusions

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

So I am using the `json_encode` function to strip out any malicious script being entered but is there a way I can make an exception as I have a fair amount of data I am copying from word docs and PDF's which have the '-' & ':' characters and if I include those as soon the browser reads one of those characters it stops rendering the string at that point?

My app is set to use UTF8 both in the meta tag and also inside of my config file but also tried including `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` but to no avail...

Here is an example of my full script:

```
    <script> 
    var iframe = document.getElementById('editor'), 
    iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document; 
    iframedoc.body.innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($row[3]); ?>; 
    </script>
```

Comment: and what about `" <?php echo json_encode($row[3]); ?>"`?

Comment: Huh? Where am I adding this?

Comment: @phpcoder it's just not good practice. You should create a hidden input with the information OR do an XMLHTTPrequest and have a controller get the information.

Comment: The hidden input is a textarea

Comment: the iframe literally overlays it and displays the content it is a custom light WYSIWYG - Plus my question is not around 'bad practices' I am asking about JSON_ENCODE

Comment: @phpcoder He meant the `<input type="hidden">`.

Comment: @fsacer Really? I would never have guessed lol Anyway do you also have anything constructive to say? this site is becoming increasingly worse by people not actually helping but being troll like

Comment: @phpcoder Sure I think you should output php inside javascript string.

Comment: Well no it isnt....It works just fine if I include plain text and a number of characters but I have tested against the '-' & ':' characters there must be a list of chars I can exlude

Comment: I think this is stoping the rendering of string as @Toumash posted.

Comment: @fsacer It does output just a certain number of characters which I assume it fails to recognise so it stops at that character - is there a way to exclude these characters?

Comment: @phpcoder Did you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663743/how-to-keep-json-encode-from-dropping-strings-with-invalid-characters.

Comment: I have read it earlier yeah...

Comment: Is it working? `iframedoc.body.innerHTML ='<?php echo json_encode($row[3]); ?>';`?

Comment: @Toumash that is no different from what I have...? - ignore that I saw you added "" but not that kills the output now

Comment: no different but `' '`

Comment: HTML recognises `&` symbols as special characters and it is searching for right symbol to use like [HERE](http://www.webstandards.org/learn/reference/charts/entities/markup_entities/) thats the problem i think. Just test it

Comment: @Toumash I know that it isnt recognising symbols hence why I am asking how can you Exclude certain characters

Comment: @Toumash so if I copy and paste a doc in with the chars like ', - and & how do I go about it picking up those characters and changing them to their HEX code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82381/discussion-between-phpcoder-and-toumash).

Comment: htmlspecialchars(json...);?

Comment: @Toumash could you show me a full example?