# Json Decode giving empty result if there is any special character is there

Tags: php, json, decoder

While using `json_decode`, if there exist any special charecter like "Question mark with Black Diamond" then decode returns empty values.

I have used UTF-8 encode also.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be in the `json_encode` part and not in the `json_decode` part.

Take a look at this:
[How to keep json_encode() from dropping strings with invalid characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663743/how-to-keep-json-encode-from-dropping-strings-with-invalid-characters)

They suggest to use [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) before you `json_encode` the string to be sure to remove all illegal characters.

To quote the example given:

```
$stripped_of_invalid_utf8_chars_string = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $orig_string);
if ($stripped_of_invalid_utf8_chars_string !== $orig_string) {
    // one or more chars were invalid, and so they were stripped out.
    // if you need to know where in the string the first stripped character was, 
    // then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475437/find-first-character-that-is-different-between-two-strings
}
$json = json_encode($stripped_of_invalid_utf8_chars_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_portability_issues - this is what you want? :) Try to print it as UTF sign.