# how to get value of array (not json) in ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have an api gives result like

```
    Array ( [status] => success 
            [message] => Data available 
            [response] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array (
                          [id] => 1 [name] =>abc
                         ) 
            [1] => Array (
                          [id] => 2 [name] => xyz 
                         ) 
                 ) 
           )
```

how can i access each id and name using ajax call in javascript ?
I am using below ajax request

```
   $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'myapiurl',
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            alert(data.response); //undefined
        }
    });
```

Comment: what you have there is a string m'a men

Comment: never seen a api that returns a string of a php array

Comment: actually in string there are passing some dutch language character which are not supported in json format

Comment: @Kirankumar Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663743/how-to-keep-json-encode-from-dropping-strings-with-invalid-characters) helps?

Answer (score 2):

Your api should return result in JSON rather than array. Once the data is in json you can access it like `data.success`, `data.message`, etc.

It seems like your api is in PHP, you can use [`json_encode($data);`](https://php.net/json_encode)